# Switch rails app from "latest stable" rails gem to "bleeding edge"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

Recently I wrote a new app using "latest table rails"

However, some issues exist, and they are fixed in the "bleeding edge".

So how do I tell my application to use the "bleeding edge" which I assume is newer than "latest stable"

Answer (score 0):

Rails depends on arel, so you need to manually grab them both. At the moment this is the bleeding edge of each:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.0.alpha', github: 'rails/rails', ref: 'abfd091980faaa4404db5fbfdf77c68a35684d08'

gem 'arel', '~> 8.0', github: 'rails/arel', ref: 'd6af2090b16f7d061aa43913d610c6fada58b7e2'
```

[rails/rails commit history](https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/master)

[rails/arel commit history](https://github.com/rails/arel/commits/master)

Add those to your Gemfile and run `bundle`.

Supposing there aren't any conflicts you should get an output that looks like this:

```
19:46:18$ bundle
Fetching https://github.com/rails/rails.git
Fetching https://github.com/rails/arel.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 12.0.0
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.4
Installing i18n 0.8.0 (was 0.7.0)
Using minitest 5.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.3
Installing erubi 1.5.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using rack 2.0.1
Installing nio4r 2.0.0 (was 1.2.1) with native extensions
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 8.0.0 (was 7.1.4) from https://github.com/rails/arel.git (at d6af209@d6af209)
Using bundler 1.13.1
Using byebug 9.0.6
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using thor 0.19.4
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using ffi 1.9.17
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using rb-fsevent 0.9.8
Using puma 3.6.2
Using sass 3.4.23
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using sqlite3 1.3.13
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.7.0.1
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 (was 0.6.4) with native extensions
Using mime-types 3.1
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.4
Using rb-inotify 0.9.7
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using activesupport 5.1.0.alpha (was 5.0.1) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at abfd091@abfd091)
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using mail 2.6.4
Using listen 3.0.8
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.2
Using globalid 0.3.7
Using activemodel 5.1.0.alpha (was 5.0.1) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at abfd091@abfd091)
Using jbuilder 2.6.1
Using spring 2.0.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using activejob 5.1.0.alpha (was 5.0.1) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at abfd091@abfd091)
Using activerecord 5.1.0.alpha (was 5.0.1) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at abfd091@abfd091)
Using spring-watcher-listen 2.0.1
Using actionview 5.1.0.alpha (was 5.0.1) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at abfd091@abfd091)
Using actionpack 5.1.0.alpha (was 5.0.1) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at abfd091@abfd091)
Using actioncable 5.1.0.alpha (was 5.0.1) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at abfd091@abfd091)
Using actionmailer 5.1.0.alpha (was 5.0.1) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at abfd091@abfd091)
Using railties 5.1.0.alpha (was 5.0.1) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at abfd091@abfd091)
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.2.1
Using jquery-rails 4.2.2
Using web-console 3.4.0
Using rails 5.1.0.alpha (was 5.0.1) from https://github.com/rails/rails.git (at abfd091@abfd091)
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
Bundle complete! 16 Gemfile dependencies, 62 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
~/test_application
19:49:25$
```

Which shows Rails at the bleeding edge: `abfd091`, at the moment.

The usual words of warning should be included here that it's very dangerous to use the bleeding edge over the latest stable release!